# It's impossible to have $A_0\in A_1\in A_2\in\ldots\in A_n\in A_0$

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

> Show that the cycle $A_0\in A_1\in A_2\in\ldots\in A_n\in A_0$ is impossible for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

I proved it by contradiction. Meaning, suppose it's possible, then it is possible when $n=1$ as well. Thus, $A_0\in A_1\in A_0$ is true.

By the axiom of pairing, exists a set $A$ s.t. $x\in A$ iff $x=A_0$ o $x=A_1$. I.e., $A=\{A_0,A_1\}$ is a set.

Now, by the axiom of foundation we know that in every non-empty set $A$, $\exists u\in A$ s.t., for all $x$, if $x\in A$, then $x\notin u$. Take the set $A=\{A_0,A_1\}$. We have two cases:

- $u=A_0$.

  $x=A_1\in A$ and $x=A_1\in u$, because $A_0\in A_1\in A_0$.
- $u=A_1$.

  $x=A_0\in A$ and $x=A_0\in u$, because $A_0\in A_1\in A_0$.

Thus, $A$ does not meets the axiom of foundation. Therefore, it's impossible that $A_0\in A_1\in A_2\in\ldots\in A_n\in A_0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.$\blacksquare$

Is my proof correct? I suspect that I have to use induction instead of what I did here.

Comment: You assumed (toward a contradiction) that a cycle of some length $n$ is possible, and then you immediately decided that it would be possible also for $n=1$. How would you justify that step?

Comment: Right. The negation converts into exists a cycle of some length, but not for all lengths. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: A similar argument applies to the general case.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen So to prove it it's with supposing that it's not true, i.e., exists some $m\in\Bbb N$ for which the cycle applies and then I can prove it using the same idea, right?

Comment: @Mystery Yes, that’s right. Show a cycle can’t exist for arbitrary $n$ by the same idea you used for $n=1$.